# RoutingError No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to visit new action of a controller from different `haml`

```
= button_to 'Demo', new_demo_path, {class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'}
```

But i am getting the error:

```
No route matches
```

My route already has the path:

```
/demos/new(.:format)
```

Also in my route file:

```
resources :demos
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: "No route matches" has a lot more information. Please post that information

Comment: There has to be something else going on here as its very easy to verify that `resources :demos` generates the named path helper `new_demo_path`. Start with the full error message as suggested by @engineersmnky and try making a minimal example that reproduces the behavior. My guess is that its some sort of slop error and making the example will let you solve it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `/demos/new(.:format)` as `resources :demos` will create the [`Crud Actions`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) including for `new`, restart the server and check again.

Also you need to add `method: :get` as button_to by default generate the method `post`

Change

```
= button_to 'Demo', new_demos_path, {class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'}
```

To

```
= button_to 'Demo', new_demo_path, method: :get, {class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'}
```